# Gulp + Browserify + Globs

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I am using the [recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/recipes/browserify-with-globs.md) from the official gulp repo, to make browserify work for multiple entry points. It worked out fine, when I followed the recipe for a single file, but when I try to run the task now, it prints

```
the following tasks did not complete: browserify.
Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Unfortunately. I am using Gulp 4 for this. This is my adapted task:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    var bundledStream = through();
bundledStream.pipe(source('./public/static/js-dev/bundles/*.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .on('error', gutil.log)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(local.jsDist+'/bundles'));
globby(['./public/static/js-dev/bundles/*.js'], function(err, entries) {
    if (err) {
        bundledStream.emit('error', err);
        return;
    }
    var b = browserify({
        entries: entries,
        debug: true
    });
    b.bundle().pipe(bundledStream);
});
return bundledStream;
});
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong - I just want this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to callback the task zo add done to the function as argument and call it at last in your function as done();

Comment: It would be more of help if you could elaborate, preferably including whole corrected block.